# Possible to rewrite routes via Rails routes like the following

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

We would like to run the 'rails/mailers' routes for previewing emails, like

```
http://domain.dev/rails/mailers
```

I'd like to have this url be

```
http://domain.dev/admin/admin_email_preview
```

and the subsequent URL request to change from rails/mailers -> admin/admin_email_preview like:

```
http://domain.dev/rails/mailers/account/event_beginning_soon
```

to

```
http://domain.dev/admin/admin_email_previews/account/event_beginning_soon
```

How would I do this in routes.rb?

Comment: Post your routes.rb

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace :admin do
  resource :admin_email_preview, controller: 'mailer'
end
```

you will also need to move your mailer controller into admin/ subfolder.